# how to display first_name in database on django

Tags: python, django

> `views.py
>
> ```
> from allauth.account.views import SignupView
> from .forms import HODSignUpForm
>
> class HodSignUp(SignupView):
>
>       template_name = 'account/signup.html'
>       form_class = HODSignUpForm
>       redirect_field_name = ''
>       view_name = 'hod_sign_up'
>
> def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
>     ret = super(HodSignUp, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
>     ret.update(self.kwargs)
>     return ret
> ```
>
> forms.py
>
> ```
> from .models import Admin
> from po.models import User
> from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
>
> class HODSignUpForm(SignupForm):
>      first_name=forms.CharField(required=False)
>      last_name=forms.CharField(required=False)
>
> class Meta:
>     model= Admin
>     fields = ['first_name','last_name']
>
> def save(self,request):
>     user = super(HODSignUpForm, self).save(request)
>     user.is_hod = True
>     user= User(first_name=self.cleaned_data.get('first_name'),
>     last_name=self.cleaned_data.get('last_name'))
>     user.save()
>     return user
> ```

models.py

> ```
> from po.models import User
> class Admin(models.Model):
>      user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
>      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column='first_name')
>      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column='last_name')
> ```
>
> po.models.py
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
>    class User(AbstractUser):
>       is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
>       is_hod= models.BooleanField(default=False)
>       first_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
>       last_name=models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
> ```

**admin.py**

```
from po.models import User
 
 class Schooladmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ("id","is_active","is_hod","first_name","last_name")
        list_filter = ("is_active","is_hod")
        add_fieldsets = (
         ('Personal Info', {
           'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')
         }),
     )
```

> `admin.site.register(User,Schooladmin)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WTmw.png)
i want this image show name but how does show firstname and lastname on database? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA8tN.png) here's porblem.

Comment: What exactly the problem. explain properly

Answer (score 0):

Add verbose_name when creating class:

```
from po.models import User
class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column='first_name', verbose_name='Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column='last_name')
```

Or you can add class Meta to models and use labels:

```
labels = {
    'first_name': 'Name'
}
```

Comment: Did you add here?

{from po.models import User
class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column='first_name', verbose_name='Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column='last_name')}

Comment: Edited my answer, failed to put code in comments

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class User(AbstractUser):
    list_display = ('is_active', 'is_hod', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

and

```
from po.models import User
class Admin(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column='first_name', verbose_name='Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column='last_name')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_hod= models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

forms.py:

```
from .models import Admin
from po.models import User
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

class HODSignUpForm(SignupForm):

    class Meta(SignupForm.Meta):
        model= Admin
        fields = ['first_name','last_name']

        labels = {'first_name': 'Name'}

        def save(self,request):
            user = super(HODSignUpForm, self).save(request)
            user.is_hod = True
            user= User(first_name=self.cleaned_data.get('first_name'),
            last_name=self.cleaned_data.get('last_name'))
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Here nice example on the topic   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: Try UserCreationForm instead ;)